# Password authentication for specific ftp account

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

I use public/private key authentication to login by ftp(vsftpd), and password authentication is off from `sshd_config`. Now, I want to create one ftp account, that I can connect by ftp without private key, so, just using username and password. How can i do that, if that is even possible ?

I use debian 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use different authentication methods for different system users because their login is handled by SSH. It might be possible using PAM but it's easy to make a mistake and introduce security holes.

An easy solution is to setup virtual users in vsftpd that are defined independently (there are plenty of guides). The downside is that those users won't be able to connect via SFTP as there's no associated SSH account and therefore they need to connect to a different port (e.g. 21). You would also need to manage those accounts and the passwords separately.

If you choose to go that way you'll also want to install `libpam-pwdfile`, a PAM authentication module that reads passwords from a htpasswd-style file.
Afterwards replace the contents of `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` with:

```
auth        required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth        required    pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/vsftpd/passwd
account     required    pam_permit.so
session     required    pam_permit.so
password    required    pam_deny.so
```